# Forward substitution of lower triangular matrix. How?

Tags: python, math, matrix, linear-algebra

Not sure if this is the right place to ask but here goes.

Does anyone know how the following code is able to solve for x `Lx=y` where L and y are a given matrix and a vector, respectively?

If you know, could you break it down and compare each step to how you would solve it with pen and paper?

```
def forward(L, y):
    x = []
    for i in range(len(y)):
        x.append(y[i])
        for j in range(i):
            x[i]=x[i]-(L[i, j]*x[j])
        x[i] = x[i]/L[i, i]
    return x
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you are representing the matrix as a list of rows (which are lists) - if not, just use the zip function on the matrix, and y as a tuple. I am also assuming that the matrix is square as having a triangluar matrix of another form doesn't really make sense.

The process is very similar as if it were upper triangular, except you start from the top.

- make an empty list of whatever length the resulting vector will have, and fill it with zeroes.
- Dot product the list with the first row, subtract the result from the first element of y, and divide by the coefficient of the first term.
- Replace the first element in the originally empty list with the final result
- Continue doing so until you have finished.

Essentially what you are doing by taking the dot product is substituting each nonzero term in the matrix by the correct value (that you already found), and then adding them all up. When you subtract from the other end, and divide by the coefficient of the nth term of the nth row, you are just solving.

(Typing up an example implementation now). (Assuming you have a class or function which takes the dot product, it shouldn't be difficult to implement if you don't). (python 2.7)

```
def solve(m, y):
    v = [0 for i in xrange(len(m))]
    for i in xrange(len(m)):
        v[i] = (y[i] - v.dotProduct(m[i]))/float(m[i][i])

    return v
```

Comment: While my method worked, though I did not know how, your solution proved to be much more simple and easy to understand. Thank you!